# debuild: no upstream tarball found

Tags: debuild

What is the correct naming convention for a patched package?

I am trying to put together a version of exiv2 with patch to add an extra schema.

here is what I have done so far:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep exiv2
$ cd src/exiv2
$ apt-get source exiv2
$ cd exiv2-0.23-1ubuntu2
 ... apply patch
$ dpkg-source --commit
$ dch -i
    exiv2 (0.23-1ubuntu2-DwC1) trusty; urgency=medium
$ debuild -S -sd -k1230CB40
```

But I then get an error message:

> This package has a Debian revision number but there does not seem to
>   be an appropriate original tar file or .orig directory in the parent
>   directory; (expected one of exiv2_0.23-1ubuntu2.orig.tar.gz,
>   exiv2_0.23-1ubuntu2.orig.tar.bz2, exiv2_0.23-1ubuntu2.orig.tar.lzma, 
>   exiv2_0.23-1ubuntu2.orig.tar.xz or exiv2-0.23-1ubuntu2.orig)
>   continue anyway? (y/n) y
>
> dpkg-source -b exiv2-0.23-1ubuntu2 dpkg-source: error: can't build
>   with source format '3.0 (quilt)': no upstream tarball found at
>   ../exiv2_0.23-1ubuntu2.orig.tar.{bz2,gz,lzma,xz} dpkg-buildpackage:
>   error: dpkg-source -b exiv2-0.23-1ubuntu2 gave error exit status 255
>   debuild: fatal error at line 1364: dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us
>   -uc -S -sd failed

```
$ ls ..
exiv2-0.23-1ubuntu2  exiv2_0.23-1ubuntu2.debian.tar.gz  exiv2_0.23-1ubuntu2.dsc  exiv2_0.23-1ubuntu2-DwC1_source.build  exiv2_0.23.orig.tar.gz
```

What do I need to do to allow debuild to recognize the original tar file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `-DwC1` in your version string. Per [Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version) the upstream version can contain `. + - : ~` but the debian revision can only contain `+ . ~`, so everything before `-DwC1` is considered part of the upstream version, and so it is looking for an original tarball with that version.

`dch` gives a clue about this when you added that entry:

```
dch warning: your current directory has been renamed to:
../exiv2-0.23-1ubuntu2
dch warning: no orig tarball found for the new version.
```

Usually when I do a ppa upload of a package I will bump the ubuntu version and add something like `~ppa0` and usually the target release, say `~trusty`. So for instance `1ubuntu2` to `1ubuntu3~ppa0~trusty`. The extra strings with `~` will cause the version to compare less than `1ubuntu3` so if the package is updated in the main repositories the user will get the newer version.

Really though all you need to do is drop the hyphen from your version, so `1ubuntu2DwC1` would work, or maybe `1ubuntu2.DwC1`.

Comment: If I use exiv2-0.23-1ubuntu3~DwC1 dch renames the current directory. I don't think that is what I want either. But exiv2-0.23-1ubuntu2DwC1 works!

Comment: @asp Strange, `0.23-1ubuntu3~DwC1` is working fine here.

Comment: @asp Oh I bet I know what the problem was. If you continued working from your source directory where you named the version `-DwC1` then changed the version to `~DwC1` dch will rename the directory back, but it shouldn't get you the `dch warning: no orig tarball found for the new version.` warning. So it was probably okay.